# Copy to clipboard code in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, laravel, copy-paste

I'm trying to write in javascript and I want to understand why it doesn't work?
sample order code that I want to copy: **593004485164756431**

when I copy to clipboard : **593004485164756500**

I checked for an error in the console, there was no error, does the browser affect the error? i use firefox

this my code

```
                function copyToClipboard(text) {
                if (navigator.clipboard && window.isSecureContext) {
                    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
                } else {
                    // text area method
                    let textArea = document.createElement("textarea")
                    textArea.value = text
                    // make the textarea out of viewport
                    textArea.style.position = "fixed"
                    textArea.style.left = "-999999px"
                    textArea.style.top = "-999999px"
                    document.body.appendChild(textArea)
                    textArea.focus()
                    textArea.select()
                    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        // here the magic happens
                        document.execCommand('copy') ? res() : rej()
                        textArea.remove()
                    })
                }
            }
```

on button

```
<img onclick="copyToClipboard({{ $result['code_order'] }})" style="width:20px;cursor:pointer;" src="{{ url('img/copy-solid.svg') }}"/>
```

I hope I can find the solution to this problem. Thank you

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: yes, but I dont use the code above, I use another way @Umair , the code above that I made the last number to 000 is not copied completely